# How to convert multiple timestamp in string to yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss format?

Tags: php, string, date, timestamp

I have values in variable as below format and i want to convert this value to `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` format :

```
$timestamps = "1538141400,1538141520,1538141640,1538141760,1538141880,1538142000,1538142120,1538142240,1538142360,1538142480,1538142600,1538142720,1538142840,1538142960,"
```

Expected Result should be look like below "

```
$timestamps = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss, yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss, yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss so on"
```

Answer (score 1):

- Convert the comma separated string to array using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.
- Loop on the array to convert into datetime strings. Use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. It takes a timestamp (defaulted to current time), and a format string. It returns back a **datetime** string, as per the input format string.
- Use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to get a comma separated string again, using the converted array.

Try:

```
// convert $timestamps string to array
$timestamps_arr = explode(',', $timestamps);

$datetimestring_arr = array(); // initialize array for datetime strings
// Loop over the array to convert into datetime string
foreach ($timestamps_arr as $timestamp) {

    // convert the timestamp to datetime string
    $datetimestring_arr[] = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $timestamp); 

}

// convert it back to comma separated string
$output = implode(',', $datetimestring_arr);

// display the output
echo $output;
```

**Details**:

- `Y`     A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits   Examples: 1999 or 2003
- `m`     Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   01 through 12
- `d`     Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros   01 to 31
- `H`     24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23
- `i`     Minutes with leading zeros  00 to 59
- `s`     Seconds, with leading zeros     00 through 59

More formatting options can be checked at [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert string to array using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and loop through array using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). In function convert every timestamp to datetime using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and then convert result array to string using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$dates = implode(",", array_map(function($item){
    return date("Y/m/d h:m:s", (int)$item); 
}, explode(",", $timestamps)));
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/RGHka)

Also you can use regex in [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to do this work.

```
$dates = preg_replace_callback("/\d+/", function($item){
    return date("Y/m/d h:m:s", (int)$item[0]); 
}, $timestamps);
```